# location film boom mic rain

Tags: film, boom, microphone, rain, protection

Hello, 
Just a quick question for anyone with any relative experience:

How to reduce the sound of the rain on the microphone when recording in the rain on set, also what protection we can use for the mic, blimp and wind shield itself?

Many thanks for any suggestions in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had experience with the rain jammer by rycote and found it to be an amazing addition to your kit. I am not affiliated with rycote but do like their products.

http://store.locationsoundcrew.com/en/remote-audio/127-remote-audio-rainman-boom-mic-rain-cover-for-zepplin-rycote-kit-4.html

Gets kinda heavy under rain machines but your mic is completely safe.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I've no experiencewith this, and am not affiliated with rycote:
http://www.rycote.com/products/rycote_duck_rain_cover/

You could probably rent it to check the usage and protection value.

Good luck